# Help with `replace-regexp-in-string`, to replace only first instance in every line

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, web-mode, query-replace

I have the following string:

```
// const asdf = 'asdf'
// // comment
// const asdf2 = asdf
```

And I want to run a regexp replace to make it look as follows:

```
const asdf = 'asdf'
// comment
const asdf2 = asdf
```

Basically, I'm trying to make a regexp that will comment out the first instance of `//` on every line. Here is my current implementation:

```
(setq comment "// const asdf = 'asdf'\n// // comment\n// const asdf2 = asdf")
(setq comment (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(//\\)" "" comment)))
```

But note that it is removing **all** matches to `//`, which gives the following output:

```
const asdf = 'asdf'
comment
const asdf2 = asdf
```

But I want to leave the second instance of `//` on the `// // comment` line. Any suggestions?

If your are curious, I am trying to solve this issue: https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/980 at this place in the code of web-mode: https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/blob/master/web-mode.el#L9973

Comment: Wouldn't `uncomment-region` be better for this?

Comment: @npostavs: Yeah, but it's not really clear what the real problem/question is, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are likely looking for this:

   ```
   (setq comment (replace-regexp-in-string "^// " "" comment))
   ```
2. But are you sure you want to create a string and then act on it?  A guess is that you really want to act on the text in a buffer directly, using `re-search-forward` followed by `replace-match`. Something like this:

   ```
   (defun foo ()
     (interactive)
     (save-excursion
       (goto-char (point-min))
       (while (re-search-forward "^// " nil t)
         (replace-match "")
         (forward-line 1))))
   ```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think the `^` operator would still work when `comment` has multiple lines. Thank you! I do agree that acting on the text directly in the buffer would be best, but that would require a large refactoring to web-mode, of which I am still getting familiar.

Comment: This removes comments only when they occur at the very beginning of the line, in the first column. I didn't think that's what you wanted.

Comment: I ended up using a slightly updated regex, like so: `(setq comment (replace-regexp-in-string "^ *// " "" comment))` which allows for spaces between the first column and the comment itself.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `replace-regexp-in-string` actually covers this exact requirement (or it does in Emacs 25.3, at any rate).

> ```
> To replace only the first match (if any), make REGEXP match up to \'
> and replace a sub-expression, e.g.
>  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(foo\\).*\\'" "bar" " foo foo" nil nil 1)
>    => " bar foo"
> ```

To replace the first match (if any) in each line of the string, you would use `$` (which matches the end of a line) in place of `\'` (which matches the end of the text), like so:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(foo\\).*$" "bar"
                          " foo foo\nbaz\nbar foo foo"
                          nil nil 1)
 => " bar foo\nbaz\nbar bar foo"
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but it only replaces the first match in the provided string. Note that I am providing a string with multiple lines, so I either want to loop through each line individually and replace the first match, or use a regex replacer that remove the first match in each line.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you would replace `\\'` (end-of-string) with `$` (end-of-line).

Comment: Ah, good to know! It seems like that solution would work as well - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could look for the pattern "beginning of line, spaces, //, spaces" and replace that with the empty string:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "^\\s-*//\\s-*" "" comment)
```

Comment: This looks like a valid answer as well. Thank you!